# Convert SWF to XAML

Tags: wpf, flash, xaml

Are there any products out there that convert Flash SWFs to XAML (I'm interested in WPF but Silverlight could work too)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use free tool from Microsoft's Mike Swanson, called SWF2XAML.

This is the link:

http://www.mikeswanson.com/swf2xaml/

Answer (score 0):

There is a new free tool called SilverX which converts SWF vector graphics, animations and resources to XAML:

http://www.silverx.net